# Parsing long number

Tags: javascript

Can anybody explain why Number('313010063000026**07**') ( or parseInt('313010063000026**07**') ) returns 313010063000026**10**? Tried in Chrome and Firefox. Any implicit length restrictions?

Actually I need to validate up to 18-digits number along with truncating leading zeros but prefer to avoid regular expressions for such simple task.

Comment: Why avoid regex? It's a perfect use case

Comment: you are exceeding Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.

Comment: If you also need to truncate then it's a string, not a number, and it's a trivial regex--how is that any less simple?

Comment: Does it matter that the output is imprecise? What are you actually trying validate here?

Comment: Because of that BigInt are introduced.

Answer (score 3):

The Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER constant represents the maximum safe integer in JavaScript (253 - 1).

For larger integers, consider using BigInt.

source https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: Yep, `BigInt` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can't represent an 18-digit number as a number. The maximum safe value is:

```js
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
```

which is 16-digit. Any value above that number is *unsafe* and can cause various issues with your code so you definitely should represent such big numbers as strings in your case.